# Classify values from table

Tags: qgis

I would like to classify several values from a vector table with field calculator in 5 classes based on standard deviation. Example: value = 3.3, mean = 2.5, std deviation = 0.7 and class #5 is "mean+std dev and above", than his new value is 5 (new column)

It seems pretty easy to do with a CASE ELSE statement in QGIS, but I would like to write something that I can use for several SHPs with different means. I was looking for some help here to simplify the statement so it can be easily re-usable with a new and different shp.

Comment: These values are always same?

Comment: Could you add the code you have so that others can have a better idea on how to help please? :)

Comment: This is the script : CASE WHEN "Rend_Mass_" < '2.59' THEN 1 WHEN "Rend_Mass_" < '2.91' THEN 2 WHEN "Rend_Mass_" < '3.24' THEN 3 WHEN "Rend_Mass_" < '3.56' THEN 4 WHEN "Rend_Mass_" > '3.56' THEN 5 END

I calculated the values for the classification, but I'd like something more generic (ex : when "Rend_Mass_" < x-a then 1, where x=mean and a=std dev) so I can just plug the values for x and a and generate Classes.

IT works, but I have a lot of shps to process with different values of "rend_Mass_", so different means and std dev.

See below...

Answer (score 1):

This is the script : 
CASE 
  WHEN  "Rend_Mass_" < '2.59' THEN 1
  WHEN  "Rend_Mass_" < '2.91' THEN 2
  WHEN  "Rend_Mass_" < '3.24' THEN 3
  WHEN  "Rend_Mass_" < '3.56' THEN 4
  WHEN  "Rend_Mass_" > '3.56' THEN 5
  END

I calculated the values for the classification, but I'd like something more generic (ex : when "Rend_Mass_" < x-a then 1,   where x=mean and a=std dev) so I can just plug the values for x and a and generate Classes.

IT works, but I have a lot of shps to process with different values of "rend_Mass_", so different means and std dev.

[image]